# How to create array of templated objects without dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, inheritance, embedded

I have been developing software driver for the SPI I/O expander in the C++ programming language. I have decided to model the registers in the I/O expander in this manner

```
class Register
{
  public:

    virtual bool read(void) = 0;
    virtual bool write(uint8_t data) = 0;
    virtual uint8_t getData(void) = 0;
    virtual uint8_t getAddress(void) = 0;

};

template <class T, uint8_t address>
class TypedRegister : public Register
{
  public:

    TypedRegister::TypedRegister() : reg_address(address){}
    bool read(void);
    bool write(uint8_t data);
    uint8_t getData(void);
    uint8_t getAddress(void);
    
  private:

    const uint8_t reg_address;
    T data;

};
```

It would be convenient for me to have all the registers in the I/O expander in an array. The problem is that I am not able to define the array in such manner to avoid the dynamic allocation of memory. The array definition

```
static constexpr uint8_t no_regs_in_expander = 18;
Register register_map[no_regs_in_expander];
```

does not work because the `Register` is abstract class so the only one possibility is to define the array in this manner

```
static constexpr uint8_t no_regs_in_expander = 18;
Register* register_map[no_regs_in_expander];
```

but it means that I need to create instances of the individual registers via `new` operator which is prohibited on my platform. Is there any posibility how to achieve a state where all the registers can be in one array and the instances are statically allocated? Thanks in advance for an advice.

Comment: Dynamic polymorphism does not require dynamic memory allocation. You can have an object `TypedRegister<int, 0> obj;` pointed to by `Register* ptr = &obj;`, and then call virtual functions on `ptr`. In your case, you can use `register_map[0] = &obj;`.

Comment: All array elements must be of the same type. That `Register` is abstract is irrelevant - if it weren't you would have "slicing".

Comment: @DanielLangr true but how to put them in the same array?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 OP doesn't say they want to put them in the same array. The pointers can be in the same array.

Comment: @DanielLangr sounds like an answer ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I am not sure whether it is what OP wants (if they know what they want :). I will wait a bit for a response. Moreover, this may have been asked before, will check for duplicates.

Comment: You may be better off using a `std::tuple` of various `Register` subtypes instead.

Comment: On a side note, you probably don't need to duplicate the template parameter `address` in a member variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic polymorphism is not related to dynamic memory allocations. You can have a statically allocated object of some derived class and assign its address to a pointer-to-base. In your case, it might look as follows:

```
Register* register_map[2];

TypedRegister<int, 0> obj1;
TypedRegister<long, 1> obj2;

register_map[0] = &obj1;
register_map[1] = &obj2;

for (ptr : register_map)
  ptr->write(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphic method dispatch only works when a virtual method is called via a pointer/reference to an object.  You don't need `new` to create a pointer to an object.  However, since you don't have `new` available, your only option in this case (assuming your I/O registers use different template parameter values) is to first declare the objects individually and then you can store pointers to each object in your array, eg:

```cpp
TypedRegister<...> reg1;
TypedRegister<...> reg2;
TypedRegister<...> reg3;
...

static constexpr uint8_t no_regs_in_expander = 18;
Register* register_map[no_regs_in_expander];
register_map[0] = &reg1;
register_map[1] = &reg2;
register_map[2] = &reg3;
...
```